# Get instance of terminal/command console of different platforms in C# Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, httpserver

I'm trying to understand how an HTTP server works, so I created one using C#. Right now it's only serving static files but I want to enable PHP files to be interpreted.

If I understand it correctly, I should execute php with the argument of the path of the file to be executed:

In Windows:

```
php C:\websiteX\index.php
```

In Linux (Mint):

```
php ~/Desktop/websiteX/index.php
```

Manually, the above example can be achieved by typing the commands on the terminal or command console. Here are my questions:

1. How do I get the instance of the terminal of any platform in C#?
2. How do I get the response of the terminal?
3. Is this the right way to interact with php?

Comment: Search term for thing you are trying to reinvent is "CGI". Writing to standard input and reading standard output is an approach to implement that... Not sure why you are looking for "terminal" - so not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to interact with PHP, is to implement FastCGI protocol on your web server side, then PHP and your server can interact via that protocol,

http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/

Mono has already implemented FastCGI so that you can use that as a reference.